# Error calling graph API with access token from django-allauth

Tags: django-allauth, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I use django-allauth to get an access token.

Then i make this call :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/10153430807524570/?access_token=' + 
access_token
```

And i get this error message :

```
{'error': {'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id':
'GILhd/N+d7D', 'message': "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 
'10153430807524570' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing 
permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph 
API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"}}
```

when i use the access token from the Graph API explorer, it works.

The 2 access tokens are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer for my problem.

It is a matter of **permissions** : Django-allauth access token and the one i get from Graph explorer are not giving the same permissions.